# Script to remove all directories older than x days but keep certain ones

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

I'm trying to write a bash script to remove all directories and their files but keep certain ones.

```
drwxr-xr-x 20 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 21 17:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 ubuntu admin 4096 Nov 21 16:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan  9 13:09 1763
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 16 16:46 1817
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 16 17:39 1821
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 19 10:15 1823
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 19 11:57 1826
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 19 14:55 1827
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 19 21:34 1828
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 20 13:29 1833
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 20 16:13 1834
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 21 10:06 1838
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 21 12:51 1842
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 21 15:20 1845
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 22 13:00 1848
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Nov 24 16:34 217
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Dec  2 20:44 219
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Dec 15 16:42 221
drwxr-xr-x 11 ubuntu admin 4096 Dec 16 12:04 225
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu admin 4096 Jan 20 16:10 app-conf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu admin   19 Jan 21 17:58 latest -> /opt/qudiniapp/1848
```

In the example above we'd want to clear out all non sym-linked folders except the app-conf folder.

The plan is to have this triggered by my ansible deployment script before deployment so we can keep our server from filling up with builds.

Comment: `I'm trying to write a bash script...` Please provide some evidence of this and highlight the areas you're having problems with

Answer (score 0):

Provided, all directories, that are to be deleted, consist only of numbers, this would be one way solve this:

```
cd /tempdir
rm -rf $(find . -type d -name "[0-9]*" | grep -v "$(readlink latest)")
```

As this is a housekeepingjob, you should create a cronjob, that regularly deletes old directories. The find command would then include checking, for example, if the last modification time is beyond a number of days:

```
rm -rf $(find . -type d -mtime +20 -name "[0-9]*" | grep -v "$(readlink latest)")
```

Comment: This may exceed the max command line length. better to use `find ... -exec ..... +` (or pipe to `xargs`, which will take care of that problem)

Answer (score 0):

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /your/path -type d ! \( -path '*app-conf*' -prune  \) -mtime +2 -delete
```

per man find

> -P     Never follow symbolic links.  This is the default behaviour.  When find examines or prints information a file, and the  file  is  a  symbolic link, the information used shall be taken from the properties of the symbolic link itself.
>
> -mtime n      File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my Ansible deployments, hope it will be helpful for you as it does almost exactly what you need.

I always remove oldest release on each deployment if there are >= 5 builds in `"{{ releases_path }}"` directory. `"{{ releases_path }}"` contains directories which are basically Git commit hashes (long)

```
- name: Find oldest release to remove
  shell: '[[ $(find "{{ releases_path | quote }}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l) -ge 6 ]] && IFS= read -r -d $"\0" line < <(find "{{ releases_path | quote }}" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@ %p\0" 2>/dev/null | sort -z -n); file="${line#* }"; echo "$file";'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    chdir: "{{ releases_path }}"
  register: releasetoremove
  changed_when: "releasetoremove.stdout != ''"

- debug: var=releasetoremove

- name: Remove oldest release
  file: path={{ releasetoremove.stdout }} state=absent
  when: releasetoremove|changed
```

This is what I always have on each server in releases directory (last 5 always kept):

```
$ ls -lt | cut -c 28-

  62 Jan 22 17:42 current -> /srv/releases/2a7b80c82fb1dd658a3356fed7bba9718bc50527
4096 Jan 22 17:41 2a7b80c82fb1dd658a3356fed7bba9718bc50527
4096 Jan 22 15:22 73b1252ab4060833e43849e2e32f57fea6c6cd9b
4096 Jan 22 14:47 9df7f1097909aea69916695194ac41938a0c2e9a
4096 Jan 22 14:16 f6a2862d70f7f26ef75b67168a30fb9ef2202555
4096 Jan 22 13:49 fa89eefc5b2505e153b2e59ed02a23889400c4bf
```